# How to deploy package (zip) into specific site under IIS using msdeploy

Tags: msdeploy

Requirement:
I have zip package which i need to deploy into specific site (say dev.sitename.org) under IIS.

Earlier , we had site under Default Web Site (under IIS) and we used below command to deploy it.
`>>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="D:\package.zip" -dest:auto`

I have tried  different provider for -dest , but nothing worked.

Does anyone has idea on this. Please share if any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting a [`ProviderPath` parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=WS.10%29.aspx):

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="d:\package.zip" ^
         -dest:auto -setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value=dev.sitename.org
```

Your provider might be a `contentPath`, rather than an `iisApp`, depending on how you created it. Open the manifest file in the root of the zip to double check.